# Setting different http status codes based on validation results

Tags: java, spring

I need to set different HTTP Status code for my REST webservice request.
Basically user will send ISBN number , I need to validate it

1. if user send empty request body , give error message ISBN cannot be empty
   and set http status code
2. if user gives Alphabets , Given error message Alphabets not allowed and set http status code appropriate
3. if user gives wrong format, Give error message wrong format and set different HTTP status code.
4. if isbn is not valid, Give error message Not a Valid ISBN number and set appropriate HTTP status code.
5. If Valid ISBN number then return book name with http status as 200.

I tried setting http status code but its not reflecting.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/person", method = RequestMethod.POST,
         consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<StatusBean>  findBook(@RequestBody String json) {
        
     StatusBean sb = new StatusBean();
     if(json==null) {
         sb.setMessage("Request Cannot be Null");               
            return new ResponseEntity<StatusBean>(sb,HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
     }
     if(!isNumeric(json)) {
         sb.setMessage("Request Cannot have Alphabets Characters");
        //here i need to set different status
         return new ResponseEntity<StatusBean>(sb,HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
     }
     if(!isValidFormat(json)) {
         sb.setMessage("Request Cannot have Alphabets Characters");
         //here i need to set different status
         return new ResponseEntity<StatusBean>(sb,HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
     }
     if(!isValidISBN(json)) {
         sb.setMessage("Request Cannot have Alphabets Characters");
         //here i need to set different status
         return new ResponseEntity<StatusBean>(sb,HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
     }
     
     Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();          
        map.put("book", "Effective Java");  
        sb.setResponseJSONMap(map);      
        return new ResponseEntity<StatusBean>(sb,HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

---

```
public class StatusBean {

    private String message;
    private Map<String,String> responseJSONMap;
    
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
    public Map<String, String> getResponseJSONMap() {
        return responseJSONMap;
    }
    public void setResponseJSONMap(Map<String, String> responseJSONMap) {
        this.responseJSONMap = responseJSONMap;
    }
    
    
    
}
```

Comment: You didn't post any code...

Comment: Except for the code, there could also be other reasons like a cache that it is not working for you.

Comment: What do you mean by 'it's not reflecting'?

Comment: @DilanTharaka I tried setting up my own customize Status code but it was not reflecting , as in case of null body , it was throwing Required request body is missing: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity . But i need to show the user message and http status code to identify.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/person", method = RequestMethod.POST,
     consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<StatusBean>  findBook(@RequestBody(required=false) String json) {
  // rest of the code
}
```

try using (required=false) with request body. Spring requires resuest body by default.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out, And how can i send different http status code with those validations . I cannot set everything to HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.      Sorry if this stupid questions       As you can see I am learning Spring.

Answer (score 0):

One of the most elegant solutions is the following:

You can throw a custom exception in case of a validation error, like this:

```
@RequestMapping(...)
public ResponseEntity<StatusBean> findBook(@RequestBody String json) throws Exception {
    ...
    if(json==null) {
        throw new NullRequestException();               
    }

    if(!isNumeric(json)) {
        throw new RequestContainsAlphabetsException();
    }

    if(!isValidFormat(json)) {
        throw new InvalidFormatException();
    }
    ...
}
```

And then you need to define an own, global exception handler at application level. In this custom exception handler, you will catch the thrown exceptions and send back a proper response to clients with a custom error message, an HTTP response code, a timestamp, etc.

For more details see this [page](https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring).